# delete branch/tag in gerrit web page successfully but not deleted in gitlab backend

Tags: tags, gitlab, branch, gerrit, replicate

*What steps will reproduce the problem?*

Select a branch and delete it in gerrit web page.

*What is the expected output?*

Delete the branch successfully in gerrit web page and also deleted the branch in gitlab.

*What do you see instead?*

Not deleted in gitlab.

*Additional information:*

1. normal code changes can replicate to gitlab successfully.
2. and there is no error msg in replication_log file.
3. this problem also exists when delete a tag.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=9071&can=4&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Milestone%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remote.NAME.mirror
If true, replication will remove remote branches that are absent locally or invisible to the replication (for example read access denied via authGroup option).

By default, false, do not remove remote branches.

add "mirror = true" to replication.config just ok.

Answer (score 0):

when I add a branch in gerrit web page, the replication log is:

```
[2018-05-28 19:29:54,076] [] scheduling replication gerrit_test_only:refs/heads/release/v0.0.1 => git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git
[2018-05-28 19:29:54,077] [] scheduled gerrit_test_only:refs/heads/release/v0.0.1 => [96bab7ae] push git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git to run after 15s
[2018-05-28 19:30:09,077] [96bab7ae] Replication to git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git started...
[2018-05-28 19:30:09,079] [96bab7ae] Push to git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git references: [RemoteRefUpdate[remoteName=refs/heads/release/v0.0.1, NOT_ATTEMPTED, (null)...ecf1c112a9596a6d4a9054fc26dd2158ce8a9762, srcRef=refs/heads/release/v0.0.1, forceUpdate, message=null]]
[2018-05-28 19:30:09,697] [96bab7ae] Replication to git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git completed in 610ms, 15000ms delay, 0 retries
```

when I delete a branch in gerrit web page, the replication log is:

```
[2018-05-28 19:30:31,370] [] scheduling replication gerrit_test_only:refs/heads/release/v0.0.1 => git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git
[2018-05-28 19:30:31,370] [] scheduled gerrit_test_only:refs/heads/release/v0.0.1 => [1679e7ee] push git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git to run after 15s
[2018-05-28 19:30:46,370] [1679e7ee] Replication to git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git started...
[2018-05-28 19:30:46,373] [1679e7ee] Replication to git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git completed in 2ms, 15000ms delay, 0 retries
```

you can find that there is no

"Push to git@192.168.0.224:fund-wuhan/gerrit_test_only.git references: [RemoteRefUpdate[remoteName=refs/heads/release/v0.0.1, NOT_ATTEMPTED, (null)...ecf1c112a9596a6d4a9054fc26dd2158ce8a9762, srcRef=refs/heads/release/v0.0.1, forceUpdate, message=null]]"

when I delete a branch. I think that's the reason.